# Adonuxt adonis template using env use throws an error

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, adonis.js

Am using the nuxtjs adonuxt template as located [Adonuxt temlate](https://github.com/nuxt-community/adonuxt-template) and
am trying to use the adonis Env use in my resources plugins but this fails

I have created a vuescoketio plugin in the resources/plugins

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from '../store'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
const Env = use('Env');
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
 debug: true,
  connection: Env.get('SOCKET_URL', 'https://localhost:5389'),
  vuex: {
  store,
  actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
  mutationPrefix: 'SOCKET_'
},
}))
```

But the above always throws an error

```
ReferenceError: use is not defined
```

Which i believe is from const Env = use('Env')

How can i use the ENV as specified on the adonis documentation at https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/configuration-and-env

Answer (score 0):

You need to use process.env.

Example (nuxt.config.js):

```
export default {
  env: {
    SOCKET_URL: process.env.SOCKET_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}
```

Plugin

```
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
 debug: true,
  connection: process.env.SOCKET_URL,
  vuex: {
  store,
  actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
  mutationPrefix: 'SOCKET_'
},
}))
```